# Band BLE I am not getting Body temperature, blood pressure services with BluetoothGatt.getServices()

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I'm having trouble in Android Studio getting the following data from a health band (HDP)

- Body temperature
- Blood pressure
- Blood Oxygen
  When I connect via BluetoothGatt.getServices ().

I get 9 services, including the battery level and the Heart Rate, the others do not appear, however the band does have the other data since the app MECARE does receive them, it is possible that I have to connect to the band in another way?

```
 List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
```

- My band; It is a Chip: Nordic 52832 Afe Ti1291 (P11 PLUS BAB8)

I have used an application to discover BLE services and I only get the following:[image]

My code based in https://blog.davidvassallo.me/2015/09/02/ble-health-devices-first-steps-with-android/

Comment: There are some custom services which could contain the data you are looking for. Try to read those and see if you can see something useful. This might be hard without a service description, but if the company decided to keep that info hidden all you can to is try to figure it out yourself

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, your device does not use the standard BloodPressure or PulseOximeter services. In order to retrieve the data you will have to use the proprietary services. I guess you will have to reverse engineer it. You could start by creating a HCI snoop log and study it using Wireshark.